# When does a polynomial fixing a subring imply its coefficients are in that subring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $S$ be a subring of $R$.  If $p$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $S$, then $p$ fixes $S$ (as a function, that is, $p(s)\in S$ for all $s\in S$).  A converse statement is:

> If $p$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $R$, and $p$ fixes $S$, then the coefficients of $p$ are in $S$.

My question: For which pairs $(S,R)$ does this converse hold?

Some basic observations:

1. It does not hold for $(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q})$.  For example, $p(x)=\frac12 x(x+1)$ fixes $\mathbb{Z}$ but has non-integer coefficients.
2. A direct generalization is that it does not hold if there exists $s\in S$ which is uninvertible in $S$ but invertible in $R$, and such that $S/sS$ is finite.  For example, it does not hold for $(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt2],\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt2])$ (taking $s=2$, say, or $s=\sqrt2$), nor for $(\mathbb{Z}[\frac12],\mathbb{Q})$ (taking, say, $s=3$).  [Note: There are rings in which every uninvertible element gives rise to infinitely many congruence classes, e.g., $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.]
3. It does hold if $S$ and $R$ are fields of characteristic zero.  (This can be shown using the inverse of a Vandermonde matrix to express the coefficients of $p$ in terms of some of its values; I'll give the details if there is interest.)

Comment: Seems very close to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32217/for-which-rings-does-there-exist-an-invertible-vandermonde-matrix . Note that the question in the body of the post there doesn't match the title, and the answer reframes it further.

Comment: In fact the argument you use in point 3. is valid whenever $S$ contains as a subring an infinite field. More generally, it is sufficient that there exists an infinite subset $\{ a_i \}_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \subset S$ such that for every $i \neq j$, $a_i - a_j$ is invertible in $S$.

Comment: @Crostul Yes, good point.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Yes, that is close.  One difference is that I consider subrings of $R$ rather than $R$-modules.  (I guess I could consider ideals, but all polynomials fix them, so that question is boring.)  I'm looking at the argument in the question you linked, but before I get too deep into it: do I understand rightly that [your answer to the other linked question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/487532/21467) shows the argument in the answer at MO is incorrect?

Comment: The answer at the MO question is a correct answer to the question in the body of the MO question, which is also closer to your question. The answer I left at the other question you link answers the title of the MO question, which is less relevant here.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: Actually I think that MO question is a generalization of this one; $S$ and $R$ are $S$-modules.  (Unfortunately, my names are the reverse of those in the MO question.)  Together with a hint from the comments of the other question indicating how we pass to determinants, I think that makes a complete solution.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer, if you'd like to expand your comment into an answer, you can have the bounty.